# New Ubuntu Install to replace existing Windows Plex Server

Tags: system-installation, system

I have an existing Windows 10 machine and I want to cut myself free from the windows cord this weekend. I have installed Ubuntu on quite a few machines already, however, this box has a 6TB hard-drive that has all of my Plex Server stuff (movies, music, etc). Obviously I don't want to lose this. Also, it has (2) additional hard drives. (1) 500GB SSD that I want to use for system files and another 1TB HDD that I want to use for documents, VM backups etc.
My question is 2 fold
1 - Should I remove the larger 6TB HDD to ensure I don't lose all of my stuff and if so, any concerns about reconnecting it after Ubuntu is up
2 - Can anyone chime in on suggested partitioning for this set up. I would think the 500GB SSD is sda, the 1TB is sdb with a couple partitions and then 6TB I can leave as sdc
Currently windows 10 is installed on the 500GB SSD. Also, this will NOT be a dual boot
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question and add all the new information we request](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1266404/edit): Will this computer be an Ubuntu only computer or an Ubuntu-Windows dual boot? Is Windows installed in this computer? If so in which drive, `sda`, `sdb` or `sdc`? If Windows is already there, do you want to keep it or remove it?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. On question 2, advice on partitioning of the system disks are highly opinion based. Questions that have opinion based answers are not appropriate in this site. My opinion is you should run a default installation on `sda` and leave partitioning of `sda` to the installer.

Comment: It will be Ubuntu only, no dual boot. Currently Windows is installed on the 500GB SSD drive

Comment: A classic mistake new users make is over-partitioning. There is no Ubuntu-specific reason to partition *any* of your HDDs. Also, you don't get to choose which is sda, sdb, etc. The system assigns those at each boot without regard for your preference, and they can change at the next boot. Identify each partition using UUID or Label instead. It it not necessary to physically disconnect the drives (installer won't wipe them all)...but it is a prudent safeguard for your first install. First-timers make mistakes. We all did. I have run Plex on Ubuntu for many months.

Comment: sda,sdb sdc can change, do not count on them being the same when installing.  Would remove/disconnect all drives containing data you don't need for installing.  Don't know if it is needed when wiping windows out, but other HDs might be affected if windows fast boot is on,  make sure it is off before shutting down windows for last time.

Comment: Advice: Remember to preserve (record on paper) your Windows Product Key, in case you change your mind someday.

Comment: If you think the answer below is correct, accept the answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔next to it and turn it green ✅. This will indicate that the answer is correct and help others with the same problem. You can also up-vote my answer to show your appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

## Q 1: Should I remove the larger 6TB HDD?

## Answer: You don't need to, if you are very very careful

I assume the drive you want to install Ubuntu is `/dev/sda`, and the other two drives are `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. Specifically the larger 6TB HDD is `/dev/sdc`.

As you know the Ubuntu installation process shows you a dialog regarding which drive and partition(s) will be modified when you press the <kbd>Install Now</kbd> button:

[image]

In the image above the drive `sdb` will be used to install Ubuntu.

Your installation should say `sda`, assuming that is the right drive where you want to install Ubuntu. If it says `sdb` or `sdc`, then use the <kbd>Go Back</kbd> button.

## Q:2 Suggested partitioning

I suggest you use the **Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu** option to erase `/dev/sda`. This will delete **everything** in this drive. If you have any data or files of music or pictures back them up and copy them in a different drive.

It is not clear if you want suggestions for partitioning the other two drives. In any case, without knowing your specific needs I can't tell you how to partition these, other than the minimum of creating a single partition covering the whole drive for each drives.

Assuming you are the only user you can mount the Documents partition, probably `/dev/sdb1`, at `/home/$USER/Documents`.

Hope this helps